# Link to previous month's posts

Tags: pagination, navigation

On my homepage I am showing only the current month's posts. I'd like to include a link to the previous month's posts at the bottom of the page.

Wordpress has `get_month_link` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_month_link). I can use this function like so to get the month number, minus 1 = previous month:

```
$archive_year  = get_the_time('Y'); 
$archive_month = get_the_time('m');
$previous_month = $archive_month - 1

<a href="<?php echo get_month_link( $archive_year, $previous_month ); ?>">Last month's posts</a>
```

This will output a link like "/?m=201308" if the month is September.

In most cases this will work, but when I get to January, the `$previous_month` var will be "01 - 1", and won't give me "12" for December's posts.

Any ideas how to make this a little more fail-safe for situations like December?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$archive_month = date('m', strtotime('1 month ago') );
$archive_year  = date('Y', strtotime('1 month ago') ); 
echo '<a href="' . get_month_link( $archive_year, $archive_month) . '">Last month\'s posts</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks! That works really nicely (I escaped the ' in month's). Just a thought on the January back to December issue, It'll also need to skip back one year. Will $archive_year skip back a year as well as the month, when querying January < December posts? Cheers.

Comment: It works as you can expect. On January 2014 it will return `m=201312`. See [`strtotime` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) @Dave

Comment: This will create a lot of 404s. You assume there will always be a post in the exact previous month or year.

Comment: @Aeyoun This code is not sending any HTTP request, just creating a link, so how could it generate 404s? Sure, if the user clicks the link, and there's no posts in that year/month the result will be a 404, so what? That's exactly what is is supposed to do.

Comment: Check the database and check which months have posts and only link to the next/previous month that has posts. Blindly linking to a page that may or may not have any content is a bad user experience.

Comment: @Aeyoun that has nothing to do with the URL generation itself. If you are concerned about that, you can do a `WP_Query` to get posts from last month (even just the ID and even just 1 post). But that's another question, and another answer. Moreover, maybe the OP don't care about this because they show this link only in frontpage, they blog since years and they _know_ they always have at least post last each month. In that case, the additional DB query you're suggesting would just be a waste of resource and performance for no benefit. But that's yet another story.